# mysql batch alter auto_increment failure

Tags: mysql

When I was in the batch alter auto_increment, there is no full effect.

my sql file:

```
ALTER TABLE a AUTO_INCREMENT=140000000;
ALTER TABLE b AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;
ALTER TABLE c AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;
ALTER TABLE d AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;
ALTER TABLE e AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

my shell file:

```
mysql -hXXX -uXXX -pXXX 10000_db < auto_increment.sql
mysql -hXXX -uXXX -pXXX 10001_db < auto_increment.sql
...
mysql -hXXX -uXXX -pXXX 10600_db < auto_increment.sql
```

When I run shell, not all take effect.

When I try to use 'source', is not to take effect too
source sql file:

```
ALTER TABLE 10000.a AUTO_INCREMENT=140000000;
ALTER TABLE 10000.b AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;
...
ALTER TABLE 10600.a AUTO_INCREMENT=140000000;
ALTER TABLE 10600.b AUTO_INCREMENT=100000;
...
```

Comment: make sure your column datatype should be `int`

Comment: auto_increment property can't be set to a lower value than the highest existing value + 1.